# Esper versus Coral8 . . .Event stream processing

Tags: events, stream, esper

has anyone done any analysis comparing coral8 versus esper for event stream processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll need to compare "Esper Enterprise Edition + EsperHA" to Coral8 so as to account for GUI + high availbility options. The core of EsperTech products is open source (Esper / GPL license) and Coral8 is not, which might also lead to different pricing range and strategies.

I think Coral8 CQL and Esper EPL are roughly equivalent and also both extensible.
The two products have all software, doc and samples available online. Esper has published performance benchmark results with code to run them, altough only for rather simple scenarios. The best way to compare performance is through a proof of concept with help from the two vendors I guess.

The two companies seem to get reasonable tractions in various industries both for direct customers and thru OEM with ISVs from their advertised customer references.

http://www.coral8.com  |   http://www.espertech.com